# Scala iterate over list

Tags: list, scala, collections, functional-programming

How can I convert `List(1,2,30,13,4)` to `List(1,2,3,4)` without using mutable collection?

30 is a kind of escape number; if found, it should be removed, and next number should be decreased by 10.

Comment: so you need a way to escape 30 and reduce 13 by 10? how about if data input changes to other values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably review your code/use case because this kinda smells, anyway:

```
List(1,2,30,13,4).foldLeft((List.empty[Int], false)) {
  case ((accumulator, wasFound), next) =>
    if(wasFound) (accumulator :+ (next - 10), false)
    else if(next == 30) (accumulator, true)
    else (accumulator :+ next, false)
}._1
```

Basically you can keep a boolean and an accumulator and use it to remember if a 30 was found or not and take the appropriate action in case it was.

Note that this won't help you if you have something like `List(1,3,30,40)`, the output would be `List(1,3,30)`, you should make clear if this case is acceptable or not, if not I would use a recursive solution which will allow to iterate an element twice in case it's a 30:

```
scala> def loop(list: List[Int], acc: List[Int], wasFound: Boolean, toRemove: Int): List[Int] = list match {
 |     case h :: t =>
 |       if(wasFound) loop((h - 10) :: t, acc, false, toRemove)
 |       else if(h == toRemove) loop(t, acc, true, toRemove)
 |       else loop(t, acc :+ h, false, toRemove)
 |     case Nil =>
 |       acc
 |   }
loop: (list: List[Int], acc: List[Int], wasFound: Boolean, toRemove: Int)List[Int]

scala> loop(List(1,2,30,13,4), List(), false, 30)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> loop(List(1,2,30,40, 13,4), List(), false, 30)
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The logic is very similar, the only difference is you iterate twice the one found after the 30, so that if it's another 30 it gets removed and the next decreased.

Comment: Using 3 `case` clauses would probably look much cleaner, like this `case ((accumulator, true), next) => ...; case ((accumulator, _), 30) => ...`. Also, don't append to `List`, either prepend and reverse or use `ListBuffer`.

Answer (score 2):

Zip previous item to each item, and then decide if and what to return using `collect` and a partial function:

```
l.zip(l.head :: l).collect {
  case (v, 30) if v != 30 => v - 10  // only previous is 30 - decrease 10
  case (v, prev) if v != 30 => v     // none of them is 30 - just return value
  // skipping (filtering out) case where v == 30
}
```

For example:

- for `val l = List(1,2,30,13,4,30,15,6)`, this would return  `List(1,2,3,4,5,6)`
- for `val l = List(1,3,30,40)`, returns `List(1,3,30)`
- for `val l = List(30,11,2)`, returns `List(1,2)`

Comment: Consider a list starting with `30`.

Answer (score 0):

Along lines of @Victor comment, and generalizing:

```
def escapeAdjust[A](xs: List[A], p: A => Boolean, f: A => A): List[A] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(ys: List[A], p: A => Boolean, f: A => A, acc: List[A]): List[A] = ys match {
    case Nil => acc
    case h :: Nil => if (p(h)) acc else h :: acc
    case h :: next :: rest => if (p(h)) loop(f(next) :: rest, p, f, acc)
                              else loop(next :: rest, p, f, h :: acc)
  }
  loop(xs, p, f, List[A]()).reverse
}
```

usage:

```
val p = (x: Int) => x == 30
val f = (y: Int) => y - 10

escapeAdjust(List[Int](1,2,30,13,4), p, f)
res12: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

escapeAdjust(List(1,2,30,13,4,30,15,6), p, f)
res13: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

escapeAdjust(List(1,3,30,40), p, f)
res14: List[Int] = List(1, 3)

escapeAdjust(List(30,11,2), p, f)
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

escapeAdjust(List(1,3,30,40, 5), p, f)
res16: List[Int] = List(1, 3, -5)
```